# Can't integrate Fabric and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I've been using Firebase and Fabric on my app for a while, and I tried integrating them today and I'm getting an error. I saw a bunch of questions with the same error but all the answers talk about the Fabric plugin or things like that which I'm thinking are not needed anymore, at least based on the setup instructions for the integration.

I downloaded the new `google-services.json`

I already had the latest of this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

I already had the Google Maven repo.

I already had Firebase core.

I added:

```
 compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }
```

And I already had the `apply plugin` line for google services.

Those are the only changes I made, but I also tried it by removing:

`maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }`

`classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'`

`apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`

But got the same exception.

I'm initializing Fabric in my application class `onCreate` like this:

`Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());`

So what am I doing wrong?

The exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application mypackage.MyApp: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
    install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5743)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
    install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:233)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:207)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:440)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:384)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:342)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:313)
        at mypackage.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:738)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5740)
            ... 8 more
```

Edit: I also changed:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
            android:value="mykey"/>
```

To:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="mykey" />
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yeah, the correct answer is marked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `google-services` version to the latest :-

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Comment: Yeah I have internet permission. I was already using Fabric before trying to integrate it with Firebase. And I was also using Firebase. Only changes were the ones for integration, which I outlined on the post.

Comment: try the above @casolorz

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks.